# Use the same model twice in one request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can you use the same model as an argument twice in one request with asp.net MVC4?

I have

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model) 
{
    SearchResults resultsModel = new SearchResults();

    resultsModel.Results = new List<string>();
    resultsModel.Results.Add("posted value : " + model.Phrase);

    return View("SearchResults", resultsModel);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult SearchPartial(SearchModel model) 
{
    model.Phrase = "changed in search partial";

    return PartialView("_SearchPartial", model);
}
```

I do a `@Html.Action("SearchPartial")` in my `_Layout,cshtml` however no matter what i Post to the first method above when any page calls the `@HtmlAction` on the second method the model never ends up being sent to the client with the string "changed in search partial".

Its like I just cannot use the same model twice if two actions are called in the same request. Which is really annoying....

I have even changed the first method to just use 1 parameter but it always just comes back with whatever was posted rather than what I set it to server side!!!

Comment: I don't see two actions being called in the same request.  Are you expecting the model defined in the Search action to get the Phrase set in the SearchPartial action when it is executed on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine. I just tested the following:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model) 
{
    SearchResults resultsModel = new SearchResults();

    resultsModel.Results = new List<string>();
    resultsModel.Results.Add("posted value : " + model.Phrase);

    return View("SearchResults", resultsModel);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult SearchPartial(SearchModel model) 
{
    model.Phrase = "changed in search partial";

    return PartialView("_SearchPartial", model);
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string Phrase { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResults
{
    public List<string> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**SearchResults.cshtml:**

```
@model SearchResults

@foreach (var item in Model.Results) {
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

**_SearchPartial.cshtml:**

```
@model SearchModel
<strong>Search Phrase:</strong> @Model.Phrase
```

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Partial Contents</h2>
            @Html.Action("SearchPartial", "Home")
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Body Contents</h2>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result** (with query string: "?phrase=Test"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Partial Contents</h2>
            <strong>Search Phrase:</strong> changed in search partial
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Body Contents</h2>
            <div>posted value : Test</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make a call using `@Html.Action("SearchPartial")` it's treating it as a brand new request to an action called SearchPartial, it doesn't implicitly carry over any model or TempData from the parent action. You have to do this yourself.

> **Edit:** From what Chris has mentioned in a comment below, the ChildAction will however attempt to bind it's input model using the
>   parameters that were passed to the parent Action.

```
@Html.Action("SearchPartial", new {model = Model})
```

However when ever I've done this in the past I pass in primitive data not full objects so you may have to do this instead.

```
@Html.Action("SearchPartial", new {phrase = Model.Phrase, page = Model.Page, perPage = Model.PerPage})`
```

Note: I'm just guessing at the properties on your `SearchModel` ViewModel.

Comment: this isn't completely true. Yes the model isn't passed from the parent action, but it will use the original request parameters. So in this case since the parent action and the child action both accept `SearchModel`, it should work fine with @Html.Action("SearchPartial"). What won't happen is the ChildAction modifying the model of the parent view.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see what you mean. I didn't notice that line in the ChildAction trying to modify the input model.